# Fetching new emails by Imap and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, imap

I am developing a program to fetch Emails from my gmail account and show them in my browser.
With first load of the page everything is working exactly as I want with jquery Accordion but the problem is when I want to fetch new emails coming to my mailbox with ajax.

Is there any IMAP function to fetch only new emails and not the old ones ? if yes, how can i write it with Ajax in the right place in my page.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: By the way such "program" already exists, and it is called gmail.

Comment: My program is having some other functionalities that does not exist in gmail.

Comment: You may have a look about how any [Chrome notifier extension](https://github.com/AndersSahlin/MailCheckerPlus) works then ^^

Comment: Could you just keep the date of the last email received, and then only fetch those that are newer than that one? I mean the real answer here is look at the Google API to see what options you even have when retrieving messages.

Comment: @moonwave99 I am having a look at source code, it looks like something I am looking for.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I don't think keeping the last email's date is a good option here. it makes it unnecessarily so complicated.
As I have done everything with IMAP in PHP, using Google API here would be too much way to go back again.(But if I don't find any option here I had to take a look at there too)

Comment: Use UIDs.  Every new message has a UID higher than any previous message.

Comment: @Max is there any IMAP php function for that or it's available in header ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It's not a header, it's the primary identifier for getting messages in IMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @moonwave99 suggested, there is a unique ID for every message and using that I could retrieve every new message came to my Inbox.